# What is the significance of the "0<" in the definition of limits?

Tags: limits, epsilon-delta

$∀ε>0,∃δ>0 $ s.t. $0< |x-a|<δ⇒|f(x)-L|<ε$

In the part where it says: "$0< |x-a|<δ$", what is the purpose of "$0<$"?

What if it was not there? How would that change the definition?

Comment: This allows us to define $\lim_{x\to a}f(x)$ even in the case when $f(a)$ is not defined, e.g. for $f(x)=\frac{\sin x}{x}$ and $a=0$.

Comment: So would not having the "0<" result in the limit not existing? I don't understand why it isn't just $|x−a|<δ$

Comment: The limit takes into account behaviour *around* the point, but explicitly not *at* the point.

Comment: The function that's $0$ everywhere except at $6$, where its value is $1$, has limit $0$ at $6$ even though that's not the value of the function there. This distinction turns out to be useful, which is why the definition is written as it is.

Comment: So would $∀ε>0,∃δ>0 s.t.  |x−a|<δ⇒|f(x)−L|<ε$ imply that the limit is also defined at the a?

Comment: That would imply that the limit exists *and* that $f$ is continuous at $x=a$, which is a stronger statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you allow $x$ to be equal to $a$ in the definition of a limit, it would imply  every function defined at $a$ which has a limit would be continuous at $a$.

Thus, for instance, the function defined as 
$\smash{\begin{cases} f(x)=x&\text{if }\; x\ne 0,\\ f(0)=1,\end{cases}}\;$ would have no limit when $x$ tends to $0$, which is absurd.